# Should you ever return null for a Boolean type in an API?

Tags: json, boolean

I have an API response for a user that looks like the following:

```
{
   "id": 4,
   "name": "Bob",
   "favorite_color": "red",
   "subscribed_to_newsletter": true
}
```

However, if the user has not signed up for the newsletter yet, the value in the database is null. Therefore, querying that user might look like:

```
{
   "id": 4,
   "name": "Bob",
   "favorite_color": "red",
   "subscribed_to_newsletter": null
}
```

My initial reaction was to set a default false value of the `subscribed_to_newsletter` field in the database.

However, on sign up, we don't ask the user if they would like to subscribe to the newsletter. So, I thought keeping it null would indicate that we haven't received a value for that field yet. Then, once when they accept or decline signing up, I could set the value.

However, I'm wondering if it's bad practice to ever send down a boolean as null in an API since the client might be expecting a true / false and therefore cause bugs in the client.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: "the client might be expecting ..." - It's your API, so the client should be expecting whatever you tell your consumers to expect.

Comment: For me, `"subscribed_to_newsletter"` parameter name indicates value will be `yes/no`, `true/false`. `null` will be confusing. So I'd not show null, or named parameter like `"subscription_to_newsletter"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send null by default, unless you properly document it. In that case it would be okay. You provide documentation for your API, right?

Comment: Yeah I think I agree mostly with you and Chris Martin (see above)— as long as it's documented, it's acceptable. I guess I was somewhat wondering if there was a standard practice and the general reaction to this idea. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For me "null" looks like you never have asked if user wants to subscribe só when you find it ask to de user and set true or false to your database.... next time you will find only true/false values... or set false for default if don't want/can ask the user about it.

if( subscribed_to_newsletter iquals null)
{
   SETsubscribed_to_newsletter(false)
   OR
   Ask user and set value...
}
else
  ...

But the better is read the API documentation and be sure if you can return null. 
Good Luck!